# how to read .pdf file in assets folder

Tags: android, pdf

```
File file = new File("android.resource://com.baltech.PdfReader/assets/raw/"+filename);

                    if (file.exists()) {
                    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");
                        try {
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } 
                        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(PdfReaderActivity.this, "No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

i want to read .pdf file which is in assets folder. what path i hav to give in filename. plz help. Thanks

Comment: i placed raw folder in res now. how can i get files from res/row folder?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you got an answer to this already, seems pretty old, but this worked for me.

```
//you need to copy the input stream to a new file, so store it elsewhere
//this stores it to the sdcard in a new folder "MyApp"
String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp/solicitation_form.pdf";

AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

try {
    InputStream pdfFileStream = assetManager.open("solicitation_form.pdf");
    CreateFileFromInputStream(pdfFileStream, filename);

} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

File pdfFile = new File(filename);
```

The CreateFileFromInputStream function is as follows

```
public void CreateFileFromInputStream(InputStream inStream, String path) throws IOException {
    // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = inStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }

    inStream.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```

Really hope this helps anyone else who reads this.

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/raw/"+filename);
```

replace the above line with below and try..

```
File file = new File("android.resource://com.com.com/raw/"+filename);
```

and place your PDF file raw folder instead of asset. Also change com.com.com with your package name.

Comment: hi,  thanks for ur reply. bt made chage but still not working :(

Comment: dont create a raw folder in asset create a raw folder in res folder and place the file there

Comment: then how to get .pdf files name ? i was using... AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
              String[] arrData = assetManager.list("raw");... if i pace raw folder in res how can i read filename?

Comment: you are creating the app then you must know all the file name at the begining only. Then whats the need to get it runtime. how ever you wont be adding any files to asset runtime

Answer (score 1):

Since assets files are stored inside apk file, there is no absolute path of the assets folder.
You might use a workaround creating a new file used as a buffer.

You should use AssetManager:

```
AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
InputStream ip = mngr.open(<filename in the assets folder>);
File assetFile = createFileFromInputStream(ip);


private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream ip);

try{
   File f=new File(<filename>);
   OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
   byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
   int len;
   while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
     out.write(buf,0,len);
  out.close();
  inputStream.close();

 }catch (IOException e){}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but it is used for .txt file not .pdf file